# How to manage multiple database schema from simple docker?

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, cassandra, continuous-integration

For my application,i am using multiple databases.I want to run/upgrade schema for all those databases from one place(for management purpose).It is cumbersome process(specially in production/integration phase) to go to all databases and run/upgrade schema after every release or whenever some changes in schema.We thought of using simple docker for this purpose.

Anyone has idea whether is it good idea or not ?If possible please suggest how it can be done ?
I would like if any other suggestions are there.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea but the schema in cassandra will not have the same syntax as other DBs typically. The only way I could think this might work is if you wrote an application that had things like column name and type and then translated this to the particular syntax for each DB and sent that out?

Comment: We will have all schema files for databases within container.

Comment: There will be different schema files for different type of databases.Conversion from one schema to another is not required.

Comment: Sounds like its a matter of scripting something then, this is more of an application side effort than anything else. Your code would need to connect to each of the DBs in turn and issue the relevant statements. I can only speak from a cassandra perspective but you can use any one of the Datastax drivers to talk to your DB to make the changes: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/common/driverMatrix.html

Comment: It means i need to have respective drivers into docker to connect to DBs and run schemas into that.Thats it.Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @markc, it is a matter of scripting only.Connect to all database and run schema on them.Used golang as language and built docker for that.